# click on a button not available by ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I need to click on an arrow to advance in an online course, but for it to be available I need to wait for a voice to read a giant text every time.

I already got the button ID and tried some JS and JQuery commands such as:

```
document.getElementById('button58').click();

$('button58').trigger('click);
```

Is there any code I can use to click the button without having to wait or should I use Python + selenium to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to the `ended` event, so something like:

```
const audio = document.querySelector('long-audio');

audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
    $('button58').trigger('click');
});
```

here is the docs

[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event)